# MS Excel - how to prevent vlookups from breaking?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup, templates

I've created a template that consists of tabs that I vlookup data from. I need to be able to rename the new version of the file without the vlookups breaking. How do I do this? Also, any tips when creating Excel templates and being able to reuse them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Perhaps use `INDIRECT()` and point to a cell in your file that holds the proper filename?

Comment: If you for example use `CEL("address",Sheet2!A1)` the result will keep updating while you change names. e.g: `[Map1]Sheet2!$D$3` > `[Map2]Sheet2!$D$3

Comment: If you only change Workbook name, in my opinion the formula will work fine.(Reference current Workbook only.)